# stuck in angular 8 loop of errors

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

It seems, I am stuck in an infinite loop of errors in angular. I updated my local angular version from 1.7.0 to angular 8. My global angular version was already 8. Right after updating my angular version to 8, I ran the below command

```
 ng serve
```

and I got the error saying

```
"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found"
```

after googling this issue, I ran this command in my terminal window

```
"ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.0".
```

After running this command, I got this error saying

```
`"Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating.".`
```

In order to fix the error, I ran this command saying

```
 ng update --all --force.
```

I again got the error saying

```
"Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating"
```

so I ran this command

```
ng update -all --force --allow-dirty.
```

when I ran the above command, I got this message:

```
Repository is not clean.  Update changes will be mixed with pre-existing changes.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 35 dependencies.
Package '-l' is not a dependency.
```

after this, I again did

```
ng serve
```

and I again got this error saying

```
"The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."
```

I am willing to go back to angular version 7, but not sure if this will help. below[image] is the image of what I see when I do ng--version

Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are updating from version 1.7.0 to 8 or 7 to 8?

Comment: mate are u sure that u r in ur angular project while serving?

Comment: check the path in the terminal --> cd yourAngularProjectPath/ and then try ng serve

Comment: from 1.7.0 to 8. My global version was already 8, but somehow my local version was showing 1.7.0. I am not sure why it was showing this version, but when I did ng --version, I got 1.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command to allow the git status check to be bypassed.

```
ng update @angular/cli --allow-dirty
```

The update is checking for uncommitted files and failing as it is possible to get yourself into some trouble if the update goes ahead with out a clean status.
A coming up date will only check the Angular files.

Otherwise stash or commit your work and run the update command again.